# Discard modification content of variable in curl command

Tags: bash

I want to create a script to test some web service.
Here the base of my script:

```
XAuthToken=$(curl -i -s -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d '{"login": "apitest","password": "apitest"}' http://url:8080/rest-api-web/api/admin  | grep -i '^X-Auth-Token:' | sed 's/^[Xx]-Auth-Token: //g')
curl -X GET --header 'Accept: application/json' http://url:8080/rest-api-web/api/admin/delivery_companies?token=$XAuthToken
```

Result of the first command is:

`eyJjdHkiOiJKV1QiLCJlbmMiOiJBMTI4R0NNIiwiYWxnIjoiUlNBLU9BRVAifQ.KmhGpDsor4I7VVPfN1gENzcQb8Yll-wewTRorFu6qfUeaIjKNIAm5lkTkPIpuuOuSpT2U4RgXz9NhwLrYIheW45Du6LnjsyUEjjWGKB4jIW0CMO-79f_-O80pQMq0P09uwmZaqUOmARPjs8UvQYQcuCHhcHd2dB-4WMnfUl-J6USI2LdI-CeOtWDDMw5YEKHGrgnHRzxgUePNWVs-Vc-BR-tXnpkEjIfKmrYy19QUfnwxcWLEWgKisrJw5d7sz7ihfzSueyrh188GiGHTeqqiNiSIkIH8UEyZfW-5BH1Y856IkXlyUaC3abHBRYHuz-O30KwvCKhtCKkaTPVR-uqNw.89jCGtawkkWuyRtq.pQmYHaWZN-XOlbvUthjK76ewqIGd1TBF0Pt7EbA2bDnxsTsXQXyot495-u4Rsvm8-y-rscAZUZFacebMvcvZ-LhUH-jHZH6L5PALY7uvGj_SGApg_Hu8D-adNDlI1rVxNcnHjpOLuOeBdUzKAznbOytquzQNODsjP877IbLTDkWTTj0IC0OWfDu-e4rYxpf2jzZBuEbnRcC8DuvbplNB2tnbRxMjpqnKjicLY9DpYdV1T-tKUt5-sI0Bhlk6tUJ0e28g1McQReUT-sB8pO3vQreEAEsVQlysVq9rC6LiW6RNRHAZP7d6PiuhLS_D_DKVmi85junbMVimYqbvszaJ.1b7PKcZfWmVmNBbTg54nFA`

But the second curl in the script, this error occurs: `curl: (3) Illegal characters found in URL`

And after a check, the content of "XAuthToken" is changed.

Can you help me to escape the character modification?

Comment: I frankly find that hard to believe: `curl` is an external command; it has no ability to modify variables in the memory space of its parent process. Could you put the command `declare -p XAuthToken` both after the first command, and again after the second command, to demonstrate any such "change"? If the values are too long, you can `echo "$XAuthToken" | md5sum -` instead, which will make such changes more obvious.

Answer (score -1):

Thanks you for your comment.

As you can see in the following output, both declare are egal. But the oupt of the command with set -x activate, the Authtoken is changed.

Here the result :

- First delare -p :

  eyJjdHkiOiJKV1QiLCJlbmMiOiJBMTI4R0NNIiwiYWxnIjoiUlNBLU9BRVAifQ.BTri-oCE-DHYx7UZo8Kib_RoO5bx9lv7BRhEYv2yizyX2n8cwzWWhMPPA-0rDHumaESgc0LmT71NLIJEyZkwN-pXH2MgYdo2vTQhnVdFOL7rZq1rHSJvUxPvhJTbAkabnTNz-s1-Vc7WNQXmWEkngaCISdnsFQU12YfJfzhgwGZi9OOf5gmHnNtXaAxTOrDcjl84s1QI0tY5HIQ_3MEB18V4UMfcR5SSk4v_5K2yVZk-AUys3bPDw1GEZkr3rypxytNZ6wCyrOEXtGh1s8w3fFQziNnnOcgwaSkpDOdhhJWUfgN3R1Cr5tnD77vG01SZw7k844LZxiK8HXhQUj3_sQ.KAhqX5YkZPXDtVlI.d-TxeoNsuemKRfDpQe9khaYym1KACAXS9MhYfGtoIwhPomZ85hKvILeT8jXxBgIw6r4XUpgSSVNtjUzA7A-_hpu0i7ffd-Ap-YDohbCfJfCYffVO557tCuIhVvybT4qQ5EgjsX8h1V5NqIyDVIPAiDIc6hnrxWsjbwE3dmfMLxqmDLXLiYTaCUMvsxtweo-fsdIymK-REuy4DdPk8YsaITpfYj57Ee5ZphZiNfvUPixkLAXj97ycEnXbP2d6q6Aw1rYVIrE3ijGYIgW618kMs5PBvjWe"yh-76mOq9_0QnKzblZW**JytHsM6D**M8kbkGRHhwFhQSvjq9HUQVNmmKCI.Q4rq7-uzPW3Yewc8Wyl01A
- Resut of "set -x' :

  eyJjdHkiOiJKV1QiLCJlbmMiOiJBMTI4R0NNIiwiYWxnIjoiUlNBLU9BRVAifQ.BTri-oCE-DHYx7UZo8Kib_RoO5bx9lv7BRhEYv2yizyX2n8cwzWWhMPPA-0rDHumaESgc0LmT71NLIJEyZkwN-pXH2MgYdo2vTQhnVdFOL7rZq1rHSJvUxPvhJTbAkabnTNz-s1-Vc7WNQXmWEkngaCISdnsFQU12YfJfzhgwGZi9OOf5gmHnNtXaAxTOrDcjl84s1QI0tY5HIQ_3MEB18V4UMfcR5SSk4v_5K2yVZk-AUys3bPDw1GEZkr3rypxytNZ6wCyrOEXtGh1s8w3fFQziNnnOcgwaSkpDOdhhJWUfgN3R1Cr5tnD77vG01SZw7k844LZxiK8HXhQUj3_sQ.KAhqX5YkZPXDtVlI.d-TxeoNsuemKRfDpQe9khaYym1KACAXS9MhYfGtoIwhPomZ85hKvILeT8jXxBgIw6r4XUpgSSVNtjUzA7A-_hpu0i7ffd-Ap-YDohbCfJfCYffVO557tCuIhVvybT4qQ5EgjsX8h1V5NqIyDVIPAiDIc6hnrxWsjbwE3dmfMLxqmDLXLiYTaCUMvsxtweo-fsdIymK-REuy4DdPk8YsaITpfYj57Ee5ZphZiNfvUPixkLAXj97ycEnXbP2d6q6Aw1rYVIrE3ijGYIgW618kMs5PBvjWeTyh-76mOq9_0QnKzblZW**Jyt'sM6D**M8kbkGRHhwFhQSvjq9HUQVNmmKCI.Q4rq7-uzPW3Yewc8Wyl01A
- Second declare :

  eyJjdHkiOiJKV1QiLCJlbmMiOiJBMTI4R0NNIiwiYWxnIjoiUlNBLU9BRVAifQ.BTri-oCE-DHYx7UZo8Kib_RoO5bx9lv7BRhEYv2yizyX2n8cwzWWhMPPA-0rDHumaESgc0LmT71NLIJEyZkwN-pXH2MgYdo2vTQhnVdFOL7rZq1rHSJvUxPvhJTbAkabnTNz-s1-Vc7WNQXmWEkngaCISdnsFQU12YfJfzhgwGZi9OOf5gmHnNtXaAxTOrDcjl84s1QI0tY5HIQ_3MEB18V4UMfcR5SSk4v_5K2yVZk-AUys3bPDw1GEZkr3rypxytNZ6wCyrOEXtGh1s8w3fFQziNnnOcgwaSkpDOdhhJWUfgN3R1Cr5tnD77vG01SZw7k844LZxiK8HXhQUj3_sQ.KAhqX5YkZPXDtVlI.d-TxeoNsuemKRfDpQe9khaYym1KACAXS9MhYfGtoIwhPomZ85hKvILeT8jXxBgIw6r4XUpgSSVNtjUzA7A-_hpu0i7ffd-Ap-YDohbCfJfCYffVO557tCuIhVvybT4qQ5EgjsX8h1V5NqIyDVIPAiDIc6hnrxWsjbwE3dmfMLxqmDLXLiYTaCUMvsxtweo-fsdIymK-REuy4DdPk8YsaITpfYj57Ee5ZphZiNfvUPixkLAXj97ycEnXbP2d6q6Aw1rYVIrE3ijGYIgW618kMs5PBvjWe"yh-76mOq9_0QnKzblZW**JytHsM6D**M8kbkGRHhwFhQSvjq9HUQVNmmKCI.Q4rq7-uzPW3Yewc8Wyl01A

Comment: this information should be in your original Q. Please use the `{}` tool in the edit menu on selected text to format it as code/data/program output/error messages. AND be sure to dbl-quote usage of `"$XAuthToken"`. Good luck.